# How do I enable aws inventory with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-systems-manager

I have to go to the AWS UI and select "enable inventory" on managed instances- what is aws doing when I click this button? Can I do this with terraform somehow so I dont need to keep going to the UI and enabling it for new instances? I can't find a terraform resource for aws systems manager inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to import into terraform after I had manually created the inventory setup.  I assume this will work for a new setup as well.

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "inventory" {
  name     = "AWS-GatherSoftwareInventory"
  targets {
    key    = "InstanceIds"
    values = ["*"]
  }
  parameters = {
    applications                = "Enabled"
    awsComponents               = "Enabled"
    customInventory             = "Enabled"
    instanceDetailedInformation = "Enabled"
    networkConfig               = "Enabled"
    services                    = "Enabled"
    windowsRoles                = "Enabled"
    windowsUpdates              = "Enabled"
  }
  schedule_expression = "rate(120 minutes)"
}
```